# Copy large variables from another process in QThread (Python)

Tags: python, pyside, qthread, multiprocess

I am developing a program with a Qt gui in python using PySide. I use a QThread to run some functions and update the gui. Here is my QThread subclass

```
class ParseClass(QtCore.QThread):
StartParse = QtCore.Signal()
EndParse = QtCore.Signal()
ParseError = QtCore.Signal()
Out = None

def __init__(self, filename, pbar, filetype, *args):
    QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
    self.Filename = filename
    self.FileType = filetype
    if args:
        self.XLSType = args[0]
    # Connect events
    self.StartParse.connect(pbar.onStart)
    self.EndParse.connect(pbar.onFinished)
    self.ParseError.connect(pbar.onError)
```

But some functions need multiprocessing so I have a multiprocessing.Process 
subclass which is MPStuff.Consumer() below, to run some functions.

Here my problem starts. When this spawned process is finished a huge amount of data produced in the other process needs to be copied to Qthread which is a part of main Process. But this freezes everything. The above function is a method of QThread subclass above. The freezing operation is when I get data from result queue.  result = result.get()

```
def XMLMultiCore(self):
            result = multiprocessing.Queue()
            task = multiprocessing.Queue()
            process = MPStuff.Consumer(task, result)
            process.start()
            task.put(xmlrun(self.Filename))
            task.put(None) #poison pill
            result = result.get() ######HERE THE FREEZE HAPPENS
            if type(result) is not Exception:
                self.Out = result
                self.EndParse.emit()
            else:
                print result
                self.ParseError.emit()
            self.quit()
```

The only reason I do this in QThread is prevent the gui freezing. Any ideas?